# EF Migrations in orchestrator (eShopOnContainers)

Tags: microservices, entity-framework-migrations

Looking at eShopOnContainers, the microservice reference architecture from Microsoft.  I see that for each service, in Program.cs a call is made to host.MigrateDbContext.  This, in turn, executes all of the EF migrations for the given context.

In a real-world orchestrator isn't is possible that numerous containers for the same service could be spun up almost simultaneously?  And if that happened, isn't it likely that multiple containers trying to execute the same migrations would deadlock or cause other issues?

Is this something that wasn't dealt with because it is beyond the scope of a reference project or does EF have something built in to handle concurrency that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that there are numerous approaches to this problem, each with their own strengths and weaknesses.  Some are straightforward... bringing the entire app down, updating schema, and then bringing the app back online.  Some implement the schema changes as a series of smaller changes, each of which are both forward and backward compatible, allowing zero downtime.  Still others leverage built-in or third-party tools written specifically to address this task.

So, to answer my own question, this topic was almost certainly omitted because it was beyond the scope of the eShopOnContainers project/eBooks.  The right choice for you will vary based on your project's size, complexity, acceptable downtime, etc.